# From a list, how to get only the items with dates within a certain time period?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of items, each item has a date value:

```json
[
  {
    "Date Merged": "6/1/2023 3:46:53 PM",
    "PR ID": "470"
  },
  {
    "Date Merged": "5/30/2023 2:44:25 PM",
    "PR ID": "447"
  }
]
```

I want to get only the PRs of the items with dates that happened in May. I think I can grab the 'PR ID' values with: `map(attribute='PR ID')`, but I don't know how to filter within a certain date range.

Comment: You'll probably need to [write a custom filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/filter.html) in order to parse those strings into date objects (and potentially filter the results at the same time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
  prs:
    - Date Merged: 6/1/2023 3:46:53 PM
      PR ID: '470'
    - Date Merged: 5/30/2023 2:44:25 PM
      PR ID: '447'
```

Q: ***"Get the PRs with dates that happened in May."***

A: There are more options:

- Quick & dirty. The test [*match*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) *"succeeds if it finds the pattern at the beginning of the string"*

```yaml
  result: "{{ prs|selectattr('Date Merged', 'match', '5')|
                  map(attribute='PR ID') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - '447'
```

- Use the filter [*to_datetime*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times) to get the date objects and create the list of the hashes

```yaml
  format: '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
  months: "{{ prs|map(attribute='Date Merged')|
                  map('to_datetime', format)|
                  map(attribute='month')|
                  map('community.general.dict_kv', 'month') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  months:
  - month: 6
  - month: 5
```

Update the dictionaries

```yaml
  prs_months: "{{ prs|zip(months)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  prs_months:
  - Date Merged: 6/1/2023 3:46:53 PM
    PR ID: '470'
    month: 6
  - Date Merged: 5/30/2023 2:44:25 PM
    PR ID: '447'
    month: 5
```

Select the items and get the ids

```yaml
  result: "{{ prs_months|selectattr('month', 'eq', 5)|
                         map(attribute='PR ID') }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  result:
  - '447'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    prs:
      - Date Merged: 6/1/2023 3:46:53 PM
        PR ID: '470'
      - Date Merged: 5/30/2023 2:44:25 PM
        PR ID: '447'

    result1: "{{ prs|selectattr('Date Merged', 'match', '5')|
                     map(attribute='PR ID') }}"

    format: '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
    months: "{{ prs|map(attribute='Date Merged')|
                    map('to_datetime', format)|
                    map(attribute='month')|
                    map('community.general.dict_kv', 'month') }}"
    prs_months: "{{ prs|zip(months)|map('combine') }}"
    result2: "{{ prs_months|selectattr('month', 'eq', 5)|
                            map(attribute='PR ID') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result1

    - debug:
        var: months
    - debug:
        var: prs_months
    - debug:
        var: result2
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't expecting this thorough of a response. Those Ansible/Jinja filters confuse the hell out of me so this helps a lot.